# control xdotool script from keyboard or mouse

Tags: bash, scripts, keyboard, mouse, xdotool

I'm using xdotool in a loop controled by an external condition (in the simplest case : ctrl-c). My problem is that my loop is fast and can make it quite tricky to go to my terminal to control my loop while it's running.
In the following very simple command line example, the goal is to move the moose by hand and click repetitively very quickly on the target you point by hand:

```
while true; do xdotool click 1 sleep 0.02; echo -n .; done
```

Is there a simple and safe way (not a hack) to have xdotool or my script read the real state of my mouse buttons or my keyboard, while my terminal is not the active window ? Currently I just organize my windows so that I can glide outside the target window to the terminal and then ctrl-c, but I'd like to be able to do things like switch in on/off with the right click or things like that.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running a BASH script, in which there is a loop, in which you fire off xdotool commands?

Comment: Well, technically, it wasn't a script but the whole was in command line, but the difference is not relevant here. The command was «`while true; do xdotool click 1 sleep 0.02; echo -n .; done`». The goal was obviously to move the moose by hand and click repetitively very quickly on the target you point by hand. Currently I just organize my windows so that I can glide outside the target window to the terminal and then ctrl-c, but I'd like to be able to do things like switch in on/off with the right click or things like that.

Comment: Alright, what exactly do you mean by 'not a hack' then? I don't see a way to accomplish this without 'hacking it', it is not intended behaviour. There is a solution here that I think could easily be adapted to your needs: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313741/make-read-work-when-not-focused-on-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh !?? I just found out how to do it :-o : There is one thing one can check with xdotool, it is the mouse position, So one can check if the mouse has moved and modify the script behavior in accordance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather simple way to implement a keyboard interrupt, using python3 (it must run as root to capture the keys). So I wrapped xdotool in a python3 script that is able to read the 'state' your keyboard while the window the script is running in is not active.

I'm sure the below could be modified to stop/continue instead of just exiting the whole thing. But in this simple example the **F3** key is used to stop the loop.

This **probably works with python 2.7** (I haven't tried, but replace pip3 with pip below to try it out), it is **tested with python3 on Ubuntu 16.04**.

First of, you need to install two pieces of software: `xdotool` and `pip3`

`sudo apt install xdotool pip3`

Then you need to install the `keyboard` package for pip

`pip3 install keyboard`

The script looks like this, save it, make it executable (chmod +x, this is technically not required) and run it with sudo or as the root user.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import keyboard
import subprocess
import os

def key_press(key):
    if key.name == "f3":
        os._exit(0)

keyboard.on_press(key_press)

while True:
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/xdotool', 'click', '1', 'sleep', '0.02'])
```

I don't have a complete understanding of the keyboard API (or Python for that matter), but from my understanding, the `keyboard.on_press` invokes a callback (in this case to the `key_press` function) every time you press down a key. 
So if you wanted to change what happens when the key is pressed, change the code inside the if statement in `key_press`. If you wanted to change which key to listen to, change `f3` to another key. If you want to listen to any keypress, simply remove the if line and the indentation from the next line.

Please note the bottom line where an array is used to contain all the arguments for xdotool. If you wanted to add more arguments, you would have to add more strings to the array, all arguments HAVE to be strings.